# If a series converges, then the general terms converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a normed space. If $\sum_n u_n$ converges, then $u_n \to 0$

My book provides the proof $\Vert u_n\Vert = \Vert s_n - s_{n-1} \Vert \to 0$

But why is there the need to write the norms?

Can't we just write:

Let $s_n \to s $

$$u_n = s_n - s_{n-1} \to s -s = 0$$

Comment: What does $x_n\rightarrow x$ mean in a normed space? Think carefully about the definition.

Comment: $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists n_0: \forall n > n_0: \Vert x_n - x \Vert < \epsilon$

Comment: I know this is a correct proof, but why is my proof incorrect?

Comment: You used the fact that $s_n-s_{n-1}\rightarrow s-s$. But to prove that you will only need the norm condition

Comment: Your proof is actually correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u_n \to 0$ iff $||u_n|| \to 0$ by definition. The two proofs are correct (in your proof, there is norm implicitly since you used a result about sum and limits).

Comment: Yes, I use the norm implicitely when I use that $x_n + y_n \to x + y$ if $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$?

Comment: I have edited at the same moment :)

Answer (score 1):

You said X is a normed space. it is naturally the norm on that space.

By definition $\sum_{n} u_n $ converges in X iff there exists $s\in X$ such that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\|s_n-s\|=0$$
Where $$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n u_k\implies \color{red}{u_n =s_n-s_{n-1}}$$
Hence, $$\Vert u_n\Vert = \Vert s_n - s_{n-1} \Vert \le\|s_n-s\|+\|s_{n-1}-s\|  \to 0$$

Comment: But why the need to introduce norms? We can directly say: $u_n = s_n - s_{n-1} \to s-s = 0$ without complicating things with norms?

Comment: @Math_QED see an alternative in my edit